Unable to upgrade properly Angular v15 | Throwing Error | Not able to generate yarn.lock file
I am following the Angular upgrade site and upgrading the MFE's from the same.
Once I run the command ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15 , it did update the version from v14 to v15 but couldn't generate the yarn.lock file due to many dependencies breaking issues.
Fixed few of them but couldn't understand the logs properly so that I can try to fix others as well.
Thanks in advance.
Sharing the basic info below. (let me know if I need to share more details).
Package.json :
{
    "name": "xyz-ui",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^15.2.10",
        "@angular/cdk": "15.2.9",
        "@angular/common": "^15.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.10",
        "@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
        "@angular/forms": "^15.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.10",
        "@angular/router": "^15.2.10",
        "@babel/helper-string-parser": "^7.25.9",
        "ngx-mask": "^14.3.3",
        "@jufab/opentelemetry-angular-interceptor": "^1.9.0",
        "@ngneat/transloco": "^4.2.5",
        "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web": "^1.27.0",
        "@tolgee/ngx": "4.9.2",
        "@tolgee/ui": "4.9.2",
        "angularx-qrcode": "15.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
        "breakpoint-sass": "3.0.0",
        "cropperjs": "^1.6.2",
        "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
        "date-fns": "4.1.0",
        "ibantools": "4.5.1",
        "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "15.0.0",
        "ngx-logger": "^5.0.12",
        "rxjs": "7.8.1",
        "tslib": "^2.8.1",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.11",
        "@angular/cli": "^15.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.10",
        "@commitlint/cli": "19.5.0",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "19.5.0",
        "@commitlint/prompt": "19.5.0",
        "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.15.3",
        "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.9.0",
        "@opentelemetry/context-zone-peer-dep": "^1.27.0",
        "@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http": "0.54.2",
        "@opentelemetry/exporter-zipkin": "1.27.0",
        "@opentelemetry/instrumentation": "0.54.2",
        "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-user-interaction": "^0.41.0",
        "@opentelemetry/propagator-aws-xray": "1.26.0",
        "@opentelemetry/propagator-b3": "1.27.0",
        "@opentelemetry/propagator-jaeger": "1.27.0",
        "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base": "^1.27.0",
        "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.14",
        "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.12",
        "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
        "@types/serviceworker": "^0.0.102",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
        "husky": "^9.1.6",
        "is-ci": "^3.0.1",
        "jest": "^29.7.0",
        "jest-date-mock": "^1.0.10",
        "jest-junit": "^16.0.0",
        "jest-preset-angular": "^14.2.4",
        "prettier": "^3.3.3",
        "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
        "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
        "ts-node": "~10.9.2",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.9.5"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "src/**/*.ts": [
            "prettier --write"
        ],
        "src/**/*.scss": [
            "prettier --write"
        ]
    }
}

Command I run: yarn install
then
Error:
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning @ngneat/transloco@4.3.0: NOTICE: Transloco has moved to a new scope, this package will no longer receive updates. please use @jsverse/transloco instead.
warning @ngneat/transloco > @ngneat/transloco-utils@3.0.5: NOTICE: Transloco has moved to a new scope, this package will no longer receive updates. please use @jsverse/transloco-utils instead.
warning @ngneat/transloco > replace-in-file > glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning @tolgee/ui@4.9.2: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-middleware > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > @babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
warning @angular/cli > pacote > read-package-json@6.0.4: This package is no longer supported. Please use @npmcli/package-json instead.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error Error: https://nexus-emea.1dc.com/repository/emea-gad-npm-public/ejs/-/ejs-3.1.10.tgz: Request failed "403 Forbidden"
    at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (C:\Users\F792X80\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:696:66)
    at new ResponseError (C:\Users\F792X80\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:802:124)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\F792X80\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:66750:16)
    at Request.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\F792X80\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:142287:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:709:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:551:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.


As per the multiple retries, I have seen this "403 Forbidden" has been thrown with different different library (inter dependent library of @angular-devkit/build-angular).
@angular-devkit/build-angular : This is a proper version to be installed which auto got updated by running ng update to v15.
Need to understand now I can fix these kind of issues.

what is the output of --> yarn config get registry

Thank you all. Actually this was a case where it says that the ejs library 3.1.10 was getting installed but it was having a vulnerabilities in the ORG level app scan.
so it was not allowing.
So the fix what we did here is, downgrade to 3.1.9 as below so that it will be overridden.
  "resolutions": {     "ejs": "3.1.9"   },

It could be because of Yarn. Delete the existing yarn lock file and re-run.
And could you just check with same package.json, whether you get success using npm. And if you are in office network, sometimes Yarn makes trouble.
Also, just try the following way --

try using Yarn after disconnecting office VPN.
change all http: in your yarn.lock to https: or vice versa
just check your personal accesstoken validity


Thanks for your suggestions. I can't try those pointers which relates to Office/VPN as I work in VDI and zero control to do any changes.
I have already deleted the yarn.lock but No luck there.
